# Take screenshot from iframe playing youtube

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube

I want to take a screenshot from iframe which is playing a youtube video with a click of a button.

As a small code given below, What I want to do is, Whenever I click on the button it should take a screenshot of whatever is getting played at that particular time so that I can upload it to the server.

```html
<iframe id="video" width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9B7te184ZpQ?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<button>Take Screenshot</button>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Taking screenshots with JS isn't exactly trivial, and you'll probably want to use a library for it, but without knowing what you've tried, we can't help much more than that.

Comment: I tried to use htmltoiimage npm package but didn't work out. @IceMetalPunk

Comment: Can you show us the code you tried while using htmltoimage?